# Elasticsearch: Query avoiding defined analyzer / using another analyzer

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a question regarding to ElasticSearch queries. I have a field called “name” that is defined with an analyzer from the phonetic plugin.

```
  "name" : {
      "type" : "string",
      "store" : "yes",
      "index" : "analyzed",
      "analyzer" : "soundsAnalyzer",
      "boost" : 10.0
  },
```

Everything works fine so far! However I have a certain query on this field where I wanna get exact matches rather than similar sounded matches. I tried to accomplish this by using a term query as well as a text query. The term query doesn’t return any result at all and I have no glue why. By using the text query and defining another analyzer I get also nothing. I've tried the following query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "text": {
      "documents.name": {
        "query": "England",
        "analyzer": "plainAnalyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So my question, how can I accomplish avoiding the defined analyzer in the mapping just for this certain query to get exact matches?
TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to index this field twice - one time with `soundsAnalyzer` and another using `plainAnalyzer`. You can achieve this using [multi_field](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/multi-field-type/) type:

```
"name" : {
    "type" : "multi_field",
    "fields" : {
        "name" : {"type" : "string", "store" : "yes", "index" : "analyzed", "analyzer" : "soundsAnalyzer", "boost" : 10.0},
        "plain" : {"type" : "string", "index" : "analyzed", "analyzer" : "plainAnalyzer"}
    }
}
```

All current queries that are using `soundsAnalyzer` will remain the same. In queries that require `plainAnalyzer` you can use `name.plain` instead of `name`:

```
{
  "query": {
    "text": {
      "documents.name.plain": {
        "query": "England"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @imotov for your quick reply. So I understand you right, that I have to store my data twice by using this approach (...) Well, it's actually a lot of data :)

Comment: No, the data will be still stored once, but it will be indexed in two different ways.

Comment: It just works like a charme but when it comes to attachements I struggle a bit. Should it be similar or do I have to duplicate the whole attachment declaration? (its my current workaround) Simply changing the field to a multi_field where I store the binary data doesn't work. That means, the binary data is writen to both fields but the query work just for the one that has the same name like the attachment. Thanks again.

Comment: Not sure I follow. Could you gist an example of what works and what doesn't?